# Getting "Existing lock /var/run/yum.pid: another copy is running as pid ..." during bootstraping in EMR

Tags: yum, emr, amazon-emr

I need to install python3 in my EMR cluster (AMI 3.1.1) as a part of bootstraping step. So I added the following command:

```
sudo yum install -y python3
```

But everytime I got an error saying the following:

```
Existing lock /var/run/yum.pid: another copy is running as pid 1829.
Another app is currently holding the yum lock; waiting for it to exit...
The other application is: yum
```

How can I avoid this error? Or is there a way to install Python 3 without going through this route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up installing from the source code:

```
wget --no-check-certificate -O Python-3.4.2.tgz "https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.4.2/Python-3.4.2.tgz"
tar xvfz Python-3.4.2.tgz
cd Python-3.4.2
./configure
make
sudo make altinstall
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that the Amazon Linux AMI is performing a yum update as part of boot. A bootstrap action can collide with it as seen here.  Just add a sleep for a couple minutes before the yum install.

Comment: Good to know. I will try this next time.

Comment: it would be better if there was a solution to wait, which I'm also in search for.  eg: on ubuntu I use 'sudo systemd-run --property='After=apt-daily.service apt-daily-upgrade.service' --wait /bin/true'

Answer (score 1):

You could **programmatically wait** for the end of the yum process.

Something like:

```
while [[ `pgrep yum` -gt 0 ]]
do
     sleep 5;
done

sudo yum install -y python3
```

Answer (score 0):

`sleep 120`

If you are looking for the Bash command for your boot script on Amazon Linux for EC2. This will wait for 2 minutes before attempting the yum command.

Answer (score -4):

Try with

```
 sudo apt-get install -y python3
```

Comment: That's a different package manager. AMI 3.x only supports yum as far as I can see.