# AWS EMR Cluster terminates while custom bootstrapping

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, emr, aws-sdk, aws-opsworks

I am running the following command to create an EMR Cluster and the cluster terminates in bootstrapping phase

```
aws emr create-cluster --ami-version 3.1.0 \
--ami-version 3.8.0 \
--service-role EMR.sentmtEMRServiceRole \
--bootstrap-actions Path=s3://ae1-s3-sentmt-anlys/config-nltk.sh,Name="Custom action" \
--log-uri s3://aws-logs-476270297889-us-east-1/elasticmapreduce \
--ec2-attributes InstanceProfile=ec2-sentmt.role,KeyName=ae1-nat-sentmt-anlys \
--instance-groups InstanceGroupType=MASTER,InstanceCount=1,InstanceType=m1.medium InstanceGroupType=CORE,InstanceCount=1,InstanceType=m1.medium
```

and the log file has following entry in S3 bucket:

```
Another app is currently holding the yum lock; waiting for it to exit...
  The other application is: yum
    Memory :  28 M RSS (412 MB VSZ)
    Started: Wed Jul 15 08:25:44 2015 - 00:18 ago
    State  : Running, pid: 1430


Transaction check error:
  file /etc/init.d from install of chkconfig-1.3.49.3-2.14.amzn1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package EmrMetrics-1.0-1.noarch
  file /etc/init.d from install of chkconfig-1.3.49.3-2.14.amzn1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package service-nanny-1.0-1.noarch
  file /etc/init.d from install of chkconfig-1.3.49.3-2.14.amzn1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package instance-controller-1.0-1.noarch
  file /etc/init.d from install of chkconfig-1.3.49.3-2.14.amzn1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package hadoop-state-pusher-1.0-1.noarch

Error Summary
-------------

/usr/bin/python: No module named nltk
```

Can anybody please tell me what is wrong with the command?
Thank you for all the help in advance :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting "Existing lock /var/run/yum.pid: another copy is running as pid ..." during bootstraping in EMR](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27738179/getting-existing-lock-var-run-yum-pid-another-copy-is-running-as-pid-dur)

Answer (score 1):

This is late, but for anyone else running into this like I was. Solution can be found here: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=614195

There are two ways to fix. Easiest is to use a more up to date ami version. So if you copied someones command line to start the cluster, replace the ami version tag with: --ami-version 3.9.0

If you are stuck on your current ami version, you can get around the issue by modifying your yum command with a releasever:

```
yum --releasever=2014.09 install <package_name>
```